# How to combine 2 SQL queries of same table into as separate columns

Tags: sql

If I want to show the total number of male patients and the total number of female patients in the patients table having gender as a column as:
male_count        female_count
1220              1105

How do I do this ?
structure of patients table (patient_id INT, first_name CHAR, last_name CHAR, city CHAR, birth_date DATE and gender CHAR)

Entries in gender column include 'M' and 'F'

I am trying to learn SQL. Please revert with a possible solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use subqueries like this

```
SELECT
 (SELECT count(*) FROM patients WHERE gender = 'F') as female_count,
 (SELECT count(*) FROM patients WHERE gender = 'M') as male_count
;
```

Not the prettiest way to do it, but should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` statements and `SUM` the results for each column.

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS male_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS female_count
FROM patients;
```

Comment: didn't know we could use case statements in SQL, thanks for the response :)